# Handsontable - can't set thousand separator for custom cell

Tags: javascript, css, numeric, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable library for edit spreadsheet with financial data.
I'm set custom numeral format, for using ' ' (space) as thousand separator.

```
numeral.language('ru', {
    delimiters: {
        thousands: ' ',
        decimal: ','
    },
    abbreviations: {
        thousand: 'k',
        million: 'm',
        billion: 'b',
        trillion: 't'
    },
    ordinal: function (number) {
        return number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème';
    },
    currency: {
        symbol: '€'
    }
});
```

All works fine, but in some (with custom color and text-align) cells this settings not works. What is wrong?

Custom cell renderer for setting color and align:

```
function sumCellRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.background = '#FFFF88';
    td.style.textAlign = 'right';      
}
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/m2dxws5a/7/

Custom cell in bottom marked with yellow color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply a custom renderer, you overwrite the type of renderer so must set it yourself. If you look at your code, you are using `TextRenderer` and, as you can probably guess by now, this will render `text`. In Handsontable, numbers are type `numeric` and the renderer associated is `NumericRenderer`. So, solution:

Replace

```
Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
```

With

```
Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
```

It should work after that!